# iOS Fastlane build failed while uploading the ipa file to Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, fastlane

I use Fastlane to push a build to the App Store. Xcode installed version on my mac is 12.0 . Fastlane version installed is 2.166.0. And I am running this on a fairly good internet connection. What might be the issue here?

```
[15:44:34]: [32mReady to upload new build to TestFlight (App: ***********)...[0m
[15:44:36]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[15:44:36]: [32mThis might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.[0m
[15:47:04]: [31m[Transporter Error Output]: An error occurred while processing the http request for the webDAV upload.
[15:47:04]: [31m[Transporter Error Output]: An exception has occurred: Authorization Required
[15:47:06]: [31mTransporter transfer failed.
[15:47:06]: [31mAn error occurred while processing the http request for the webDAV upload. 
An exception has occurred: Authorization Required
```

Answer (score 1):

Is 2FA enabled on your Apple ID?

If so, you need to create an app-specific password and use instead.